# Installation error: No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg': 'ffmpeg'

Tags: ffmpeg

is there a way to install **ffmpeg** without having root access? not able to do so using `./configure` from the git clone `git://source.FFmpeg.org/fFFmpeg.git`

Comment: yes, if you download the static binary for your specific OS ('nix/MacOS/Windows) you should be able to run it from the downloaded directory sans root privileges.  tell me what OS you're on and I'll direct you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just grab the static build for Linux [here](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), or for MacOS [here](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/).  Then open up a command prompt and untar your archive, cd to the bin folder and make the binary executable:

```
chmod +x ffmpeg
```

You can then move your executable into your home directory, perhaps under `~/bin/`, and execute from there.